# CocoaPods : cmd-line builds

Tags: objective-c, continuous-integration, xcodebuild, cocoapods

It seems that in cmd-line builds, Pods don't get built automatically. Even when invoking xcodebuild to reference the workspace that declares how projects link to each other.

Is there a way to fix this, besides manually opening the project in Xcode and building?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any problem with such configuration: **CocoaPods 0.28.0** and **Xcode5** (+ Command-Line Tools) here and building using the Command-Line quite often (especially for Continuous Integration) without having any problem.

- Neither with the Apple's `xcodebuild` command, nor with [`xctool`](https://github.com/facebook/xctool) (see also [this NSHipster's article](http://nshipster.com/xctool/)) when building my personnal project using Travis-CI either, everything works fine;
- At work we have plenty of Xcode workspaces created using CocoaPods / `pod install` and we use Jenkins-CI to run `xcodebuild` to build them and no problem either.

Maybe you need to check a bit more about your configuration? Which CocoaPods & Xcode version, Which Command-Line Tools (`xcode-select --print-path`?), How is you Xcode configured (maybe you changed some of Xcode's default settings that broke it somehow)?

Tell us more about your specific configuration and the error/warning messages you got, because there should not be any problem.

**Also make sure you have an up-to-date version of CocoaPods** (some stuff were fixed some versions ago regarding Xcode5 and the new arm64 architecture, that **broke implicit dependency detection** in some cases)

Comment: Thanks encouraging news. I'm on Xcode 5.0.2 and CocoaPods 0.28.0, so latest versions. . Our deployment target is 6.1, we use cmd-line builds for CI, running on Jenkins. . . I believe this issue has been logged in the AppCode tracker (which also uses xcodebuild). . I'll dig up those details ASAP.

Comment: @FullDecent I think you can force the Pods project to build first, from cmd-line.